# How to center a form on all devices with single CSS

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress, bootstrap-modal

This is my page link: http://poltr.com/action/#alle 
when we click on KONTAKT NU, a bootstrap based model appears, it is centered using a query, but when we re-size the window, it stops staying at center!!!
Is there any way to center it on all devices using SINGLE CSS!!

I am using this for larger screens to make it centered

```
.modal {
    overflow: auto;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    position: fixed;
    top: 5%;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 42%;
    z-index: 1050;
    outline: 0;
}
```

What CSS should I apply to make it centered on all devices?

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery's on window resize event. It goes a little something like this:

```
$( window ).resize(function() {
    //execute centering code here  
});
```

It would be better to use css. Try this:

```
.modal {
    overflow: auto;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    position: relative;
    top: 5%;
    left: auto;
    right: auto;
    margin: auto;
    width: 75%;
    max-width: 75%;
    z-index: 1050;
    outline: 0;
}
```

I basically did that. The `.modal` div is centered but you'll have to modify the content within the `.modal` element which doesn't look right. This is because you're using `.col-sm-4` class within `.modal`. I recommend not using that.

Comment: @blunor I recommend you use css rather than my half baked idea of jQuery

Comment: thank you, I am trying to use CSS, adding: left: 40%; margin-left:-150px; looks like this is working, I just only need to use query for screens between 768px and 1020px I guess.. I am figuring out right dimensions I need

Answer (score 0):

Since your model box width is 300, use the below code. 
It will sent the box into the middle. then move it back to the left by the half of the width.

```
.modal{
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -150px;
}
```

Comment: it is already centered on larger screens, I want to know for smaller screens!! :(

Comment: this code should also work for the small screen since left:50% is rely on the screen width.

Comment: I am already using left:42%, please open the link and check, you will see what I am looking for. this is link: http://poltr.com/action/#alle and click on KONTACT NU.

Comment: I already test it in your page. Please just replace in the browser and test it out. The code is working even for mobile size (320).

Comment: thank you, I am trying to use CSS, adding: left: 40%; margin-left:-150px; looks like this is working, I just only need to use query for screens between 768px and 1020px I guess.. I am figuring out right dimensions I need

Comment: glad to know it help.     :)

Answer (score 0):

Updated Code:

**Remove--**

`col-md-4` from `div` and specify `width` and `margin 0 auto;`

`top` and `left` from `.modal` and instead of that add `overflow:hidden`

**Add++**

`overflow:hidden` in `.modal-body`

Comment: margin: 0 auto; doesn't work. This is reason I came on stack overflow.